# How to read integers from file?

Tags: java, readfile, writefile

I want to write a program that reads numbers from both.txt file and write to even.txt if its even and to odd.txt if its odd numbers in java. i need help

i have managed to create these files

I have tried the following but its not working:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
  File both = new File("/home/eddie/Desktop/both.txt"); 
  File odd = new File("/home/eddie/Desktop/odd.txt");      
  File even = new File("/home/eddie/Desktop/even.txt");
  
  Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
   int number,remainder;
    System.out.println("Please enter a number!");
        number = myObj.nextInt();
    
     
    try (PrintWriter pwboth = new PrintWriter(both)) {
        pwboth.println(number);
        pwboth.close(); 
    }
    remainder = number/2;
    
    if (remainder != 0)
    {
        
                
        
            try (PrintWriter pwodd = new PrintWriter(odd)) {
                pwodd.println(number);
                pwodd.close();
            }
    } 
    else if(remainder > 0)
{
      try (PrintWriter pweven = new PrintWriter(even)) {
           pweven.println(number);
           pweven.close();
        }
}
}
```

This code is only printing to odd.txt and both.txt even if its even number and i want the program to read numbers from the both file i just don't know how to go about it.

Comment: Think about it: if remainder __is not 0__, do this thing, otherwise, if remainder is __above 0__, do this thing. The second case (remainder above 0) can obviously never occur; if remainder is above 0, it is obviously not 0. More generally, `remainder` is incorrect - `number/2` just gets you the result of the division, you don't get the remainder. You want `%`, that gives you the remainder, and you want `else`. Not `else if...`. Just: If there is a remainder it is odd. Otherwise, it is even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note :** The operator **modulo (%)** is used to get remainder value after division
***for Example:   X % Y = Z means if X is divided by Y then it gave Z as remainder***

So the definition of **ODD** and **EVEN**

- number % 2 != 0 for ODD
- number % 2 == 0 for EVEN

Here is correct code as you have posted having expected result:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Read & Write from and To the file

        File file = new File("source.txt");
        File even = new File("even.txt");
        File odd = new File("odd.txt");

        int number = 0;

        try (BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
             PrintWriter evenWriter = new PrintWriter(even);
             PrintWriter oddWriter = new PrintWriter(odd);){

            String text = null;

            while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                number = Integer.parseInt(text) ;

                if(number % 2 == 0) {
                    evenWriter.println(number);
                }else{
                    oddWriter.println(number);
                }

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

**source.txt**

```
12
23
34
45
56
67
78
89
90
```

**even.txt**

```
12
34
56
78
90
```

**odd.txt**

```
23
45
67
89
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want remainder you need to use modulo, not division.

```
remainder = number%2;
```

Also:

```
else if(remainder > 0)
```

remainder can only be 0 or 1, so this condition makes little sense.

Your try blocks are not correct - here is a nice article about how to do it correctly.
https://www.baeldung.com/java-try-with-resources

Answer (score 0):

To know if a number is odd or even, you have to know if it is divisible by 2 or not.

```java
if (number % 2 == 0) {
  // It's an even number, write it to even.txt
} else {
  // It's an odd number, write it to odd.txt
}
```

`number % 2 == 0` means that the `number` is divisible by 2 and leaves no remainder behind when divided by 2.

`number %2 != 0` means that the `number` is NOT divisible by 2 and leaves a remainder behind when divided by 2.

Comment: i did that it worked, but then i want the both.txt file to be overwritten when ever the use enter a number can you help me with that?

Comment: @Eddie756 just write to both.txt file before or after writing to the next file. You don't need the if statement to write to both.txt .

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution with some more generic readability. Assuming that the input file contains **numbers** separated with **space** or **new line**

```
public static void filterOddEvenNumberFromFile() {

        File input = new File("input.txt");
        File evenOutput = new File("evenOutput.txt");
        File oddOutput = new File("oddOutput.txt");
       
        List<Integer> evenList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> oddList = new ArrayList<>();

       try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));
            PrintWriter evenOutputWriter = new PrintWriter(evenOutput);
            PrintWriter oddOutputWriter = new PrintWriter(oddOutput);
           ) {

           String text = null;
           String [] numbers;
           while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               numbers = text.split(" ");
               for(String n:numbers){
                   if(Integer.parseInt(n) % 2 == 0){
                       evenList.add(Integer.parseInt(n));
                   }else{
                       oddList.add(Integer.parseInt(n));
                   }
               }
               for(Integer even : evenList) {
                   evenOutputWriter.print(even + " ");
               }
               for(Integer odd:oddList) {
                   oddOutputWriter.print(odd + " ");
               }
               evenList.clear(); oddList.clear();
           }
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```

**input.txt**

```
12 23 34 45 56
67 78 89 90
98 76 54
32 10
90
```

**evenOutput.txt**

```
12 34 56 78 90 98 76 54 32 10 90
```

**oddOutput.txt**

```
23 45 67 89
```

Comment: what if i want to get all this numbers from the user or just assign them in the program not manually how can i go about it?

Comment: Just replace the **BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input))**  with  **Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in)** or **BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))** and do changes in **while()** loop accordingly and it will work to read data from console